# Is it possible to "add" a second folder to the current folder file contents? symlink?

Tags: centos, directory, symlink

**question**: Is it possible to "add" the contents of a 2nd folder to the current folder file contents? (In essence I was asking from a full Unix is perspective but may be nginx would work too as the goal is for a web server)

Example:

I have `/pub` where our server software lives. It has `index.php`
But I also have `/static/files` where `test.php` lives. I do not want to place `test.php` in `/pub`. What I want is that if I visit the nginx webserver with root `/pub` that it sees both `test.php and index.php` in the root.

Why?

Because nowadays I have add a lot of validation files to our server that need to exist in the root. Files like `bing_dfsfsfsdfs.html` and `google_aaddasdjsad.html`. It is a multiserver setup so the files have amounted to quite a few. I was thinking of creating a folder `/static/files` where I can store all these single files ... and keep the `/pub` folder clean with the software only.

Comment: Can we assume that the user access `/pub` etc. through a web or FTP server (or similar; _please_ mention which one), or are you dealing with actual directories that users access after logging in with terminal access?

Comment: [GNU Stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/stow.html) can be used to symlink the files of one directory into another directory.

Comment: @JShorthouse That would possibly not help if they are accessing the files through a webserver.

Comment: Updated the question. I was asking for full Unix support but yes the end goal is to do this for a web server running nginx

Comment: @snh_nl in the general case, overlayfs on Linux can be used to show the union of contents of two folders. By the way, if my answer worked for you, could you tell us what was the correct config syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purely from an nginx perspective, this seems like a job for [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files). With `try_files`, you can tell nginx to try multiple locations for a given URI. So something like:

```
location ~ ^/([^/]+)$ {
  try_files $uri /static/files/$1 =404;
}
```

I'm not sure of the exact syntax to be used, but the point is to tell nginx to try the default root first for the file, then try in `static/files` directory in the root and finally return a 404 if nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `alias`

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias

Defines a replacement for the specified location.

```
location ~ ^/(.+\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png))$ {
    alias /static/files/$1;
}
```